# Underlying meaning of bizzare tag

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

What is the meaning of [always-waffle-in-iceland](/questions/tagged/always-waffle-in-iceland). Is there some joke meaning. Like this is the lame joke tag? Otherwise, should I report the tags as nonconstructive???

Comment: Yes, it's a joke: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/always-friday-in-iceland/info

Comment: Mmm, bizzare reminds of pizza.

Answer (score 4):

It means that in Iceland only waffles exist, a fact that is heavily celebrated by management.

I merged the tag with [always-friday-in-iceland](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/always-friday-in-iceland/synonyms) which is the tag for silly in-jokes, feel free to ignore it.